# Dynamic hosts variables in inventory

Tags: ansible-inventory

Ansible inventory.
Today it like this
hosts:
xxxxxxx.ysp.se:
I want to add the host via variable like
hosts:
"{{ host_1 }}:"

In other yaml file
host_1: xxxxxxx.ysp.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action.yml
hosts:
host_one:
brokers:'

### hosts.yml //same dir

## Host alias

hosts:
host_one:
ansible_host: uxxxxx.ii.sys.blue.com
Use of aliases solved the problem.